# How to get calendar events for specific date?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datetime

I have an calendar event with StartDateTime and EndDateTime. These events are stored as records in database.  I want to get all events for specific date.  There are multiple scenarios that come to mind right away.

Given a specific date 12/01/2011, I want to get events which fall on 12/01/2011 (from 12:00:00 AM to 11:59:59 PM).

So I need to select:

1. Events whose StartDateTime and EndDateTime falls into range of 12/01/2011 12:00:00 AM and 12/01/2011 11:59:00 PM
2. Events that span onto next day. That is StartDateTime is on 12/01/2011 before 11:59:59 PM but EndDateTime is sometime in future
3. Events whose EndDateTime is on 12/01/2011  but before 11:59:59 PM and whose StartDateTime is before 12/01/2011 12:00:00 AM
4. Events that span multiple days. That is StartDateTime is before 12/01/2011 12:00:00 AM and EndDateTime is after 12/01/2011 11:59:59 PM

I might be missing other scenarios. I have a feeling this is not an original problem and there are methods out there that do exactly what I need. Is there a standard way to select these events?

Comment: Where and how are these events represented? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: These events are records in database table. Every record has StartDateTime and EndDateTime  which are of type datetime.  I'm trying to query these events using LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your 4 cases break down to a single statement (pseudocode)

```
if ((StartDate <= InputDate) && (EndDate >= InputDate))
```

Comment: Please note that if you change `InputDate` to a `timestamp` (as your data appears to be currently stored), you will need to compare `StartDate` as _less than_ the start of the **next** day, and then `EndDate` against the start of the **input** date.  Comparing against `date` datatypes, this statement will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

After combining solutions suggested by Jason and X-Zero here is what I've got.

```
DateTime inputDateStart = inputDate;
DateTime beginningOfNextDay = inputDate.AddDays(1);


IQueryable<MyEvent> inputDayEvents = (<collection of all the events here>)
.Where(e => e.StartDateTime < beginningOfNextDay && e.EndDateTime >= inputDateStart)
```

Here is a visual representation of query.

[image]